# Generate all combinations that do not already exist between two tables and union them with the ones that already exist SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

- A
- B
- C

C is an association class between A and B. Meaning that there is a many to many relationship between A and B. C also has fields of its own that are not the primary keys of A/B.

I want to return all the fields in C for a given A.ID (PK). Now this part might return 0 to * results. But I always want to return the same number of results as there are records in B. That is I want to fill in the missing combinations between A.ID and B (that do not exist in C) with Null Values.

SAMPLE:
[image]

I am trying to do this within Access.
In case it helps, here is an image with the specific tables and their fields that I am trying to do this with.

Where A is ASCs, B is Flights, and C is FlightHistory.

[image]

Comment: Please add sample input data and the expected result.

Comment: You want *"**all** combinations"?* This sounds like it could give some unexpected results.  Joins are intended to *limit* the possible combinations of links between tables.  If you want *all* combinations, you would not use Joins at all.  As stated, some sample data and an example of expected results could shed some light on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 queries, one that selects all IDs of B together with the desired AID, and one query that selects all these combinations, outer-joined to the existing combinations in C. This can be written in a single query (with a subquery) like this:

```
SELECT AB.AID, AB.BID, C.Desc
FROM (SELECT A.AID, B.BID FROM A, B WHERE (((A.AID)=1))) AB
LEFT JOIN C ON (AB.BID = C.BID) AND (AB.AID = C.AID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could union two result sets together, one which gets the primary records from C with another that gets the missing entries from B...

```
SELECT * FROM C WHERE C.AID = 1
UNION
SELECT 1 as AID, ID as BID, '' as Desc FROM B WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT BID FROM C WHERE C.AID = 1)
ORDER BY BID;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d110/11/0